# Draw circle and rectangle in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and I want to draw circle and rectangle by using java code. I did write code for that purpose and tried at my own. But on Panel is appearing and shapes are not appearing.

Code of "MyPanel" is given below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    public void painComponent(Graphics g){  
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawRect(20,20,20,20);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillOval(50,20,20,20);
        g2.drawString("Hello World", 120, 50);
    }//end painComponent 
}//end test class
```

Cdoe of driver class "Test" is given below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Test{
    JFrame f; 
    MyPanel p; 
    public Test(){
        f = new JFrame();
        Container c = f.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        p = new MyPanel(); 
        c.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }//end of constructor
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

And as per my knowledge when frame becomes visible through the `paintChildren()` method then panel should become visible 
Also to become visible panel will call `paintComponent()` method which will  do your custom drawing, but it seems like panel is not calling `paintComponent()`.

Comment: Add the "@Override" annotation to the methods you think you're overriding, it will cause a compiler error when you're wrong

Comment: can you clear more what you want to know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some spelling mistake. Method inside “MyPanel” is painComponent()  rather paintComponent()

“t” is missing from your prototype that is why your program was not able to override paintComponent() in MyPanel class.

So all you have to do is that just update your code and replace with “paintComponent();”

Complete class code is given below,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){  
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawRect(20,20,20,20);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillOval(50,20,20,20);
        g2.drawString("Hello World", 120, 50);
    }//end painComponent 
}//end test class
```

I have tested this code it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your method in `MyPanel` is called `painComponent` :-).

That is why the method from the base class is called, your method does not override any method from `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

In MyPanel class, the method name should be `paint`, instead of `painComponent`.
It is an overridden method, hence, the name matters.
Please change the name of the method to "paint" and try.